# Real tree and simplicial tree

Tags: trees, gromov-hyperbolic-spaces

A real tree is a metric space $(X,d)$ such that for any points $x,y\in X$ there is a unique path from $x$ to $y$, and which is a geodesic. Equivalently, it is a $0$-hyperbolic space.

A simplicial tree (by this I mean a graph that is a tree) can be seen as a real tree, but not all real trees come from simplicial tree.

Now, given a metric space $(X,d)$, an ultrafilter $\omega$ on $\mathbb{N}$ non-principal, a sequence $u=(u_n)\in \mathbb{R}$ and a sequence of points $p=(p_n)\in X$, there is a way to define the ultralimite $X_\infty(d,u,p)$: we consider the set of sequence $(x_n)$ of points of $X$, such that the sequence $\frac{d(x_n,p_n)}{u_n}$ is bounded, we define a pseudo-distance $d(x,y)=\underset{\omega}{\lim} \frac{d(x_n,y_n)}{u_n}$ and we take a quotient, with $x\sim y$ iff $d(x,y)=0$ to get a metric space called the ultralimit of $X$.

A few things I know:

1. If $X$ is a real tree, so is the limit, because if $X$ is $0$-hyperbolic the ultralimit is too.
2. In fact, in $u_n\to \infty$, then if $X$ is only $\delta$-hyperbolic, the ultralimit is $0$-hyperbolic thus a real tree.
3. From what I have seen, the case $u_n\to \infty$ seems to be often considered an is called the asymptotic cone of $X$

Now my question is, if $X$ is a simplicial tree, we can see it as a real tree and consider an ultralimit $X_\infty$, and so this metric space is a real tree. Are there cases when we can say this real tree comes from a simplicial tree ?

I have a feeling that if $u_n$ does not go to $\infty$, it might be the case - and maybe this is why it is not considered, because we do not get "more complicated space" ?) but although seeing a simplicial tree as a real tree is not that hard, I find it hard to do the converse and given a real tree, understand wether it comes from a simplicial tree or not.

Comment: I very much doubt this. Even when the limiting tree is simplicial (which happens sometimes), it can either come from a real tree or from a simplicial tree. Under very mild assumptions, limiting trees are universal and their only invariant is the cardinality of branching (all points have the same cardinality of branching). Is there any reason you are asking? IMHO, it's a wrong question to ask.